# Linkify on TextView missing out on question mark

Tags: android, textview

I create a clickable link with

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Passwort vergessen?");
    Linkify.addLinks(forgotPasswordTextView, pattern, "something://");
```

The link works, but the result looks like this:

[image]

the question mark isn't linkified. I both tried putting the String

> Passwort vergessen?

plain inside code/XML as well as within `strings.xml`, I laso tried  replacing the ? with `&#63;`, to no avail.

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
forgotPasswordTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://google.com/'>Passwort vergessen?</a>)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Passwort vergessen?");
     Linkify.addLinks(forgotPasswordTextView, pattern, Linkify.ALL);
```

Or you can remove the `Linkify` and add this in your XML

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Also you can see [android-creating-links-using-linkfy](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/01/27/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/)